# Where can I find the definitions for Cipher/Kex/etc groups in Linux's crypto-policies?

Tags: cryptography

I just ran a security scan on a new server, and one of the lower-priority recommendations was to disable all key exchange algorithms that use SHA-1 (for example, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1).

I started digging into the crypto-policies, and I see that name in the opensshserver back-end, but nowhere else.  What I do see throughout the polices is all-uppercase short names, such as SHA1 and DHE-RSA. I also found the python script that put those groups/suites in the "ALL_*" groups.  What I can't find is the document/web page/script/man page that says what algorithms go into each group, or for that matter, what each name is supposed to signify.

Can somebody tell me where I can find that information?  With Linux distros integrating crypto-policies more with each major release, I suspect it's going to be a good thing to know the ins-and-outs of crypto-policies.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things being discussed here.  The set of cipher suites you're referring to are used for TLS.  SSH does not use TLS; instead, it has its own way of negotiating algorithms.  Both are secure when used correctly.

If you want to see the algorithms supported by your version of OpenSSH, you can use the `-Q` option.  The arguments to that option differ between versions, so you should look at the manual page to determine which options yours supports.  If you have a very old version of OpenSSH, then it may not support the `-Q` option, but I don't believe any of those systems have security support anymore, and then you'd want to upgrade for that reason instead.

It is always best to avoid the use of SHA-1 wherever possible, although in this case SHA-1 is used as a sort of PRF and isn't intrinsically insecure.  However, because of its 160-bit length, it's not possible to get 256-bit security here, and of course both MD5 and SHA-1 are obsolete and better options are widely available.

You should similarly avoid the use of RSA keys with SHA-1 and all DSA keys.  RSA keys can be secure if used with SHA-2 (that is, signature algorithms `rsa-sha2-512` and `rsa-sha2-256` instead of `ssh-rsa`).  Ed25519 keys are preferred and avoid this entire problem.

For a secure configuration, I recommend the [Mozilla SSH configuration](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh.html), which is simple and easy to follow.